# How to keep all elements in place at different resolutions - HTML/CSS3

Tags: html, css, page-layout

I have been working on this page layout for a while now, placing all elements in specific positions, however, whenever I either resize the browser or change to a different resolution, everything moves around. Anyone knows how to fix that? Here are both my HTML and CSS codes:

HTML:

```
<body>

 <a> href="link"><img id="logo" src="images/umass.gif" alt="UMASS Boston"></a>
 <nav id="top_bar">  
  <ul>
   <li><link>Home</a></li>
   <li><link>Admissions</a></li>
   <li><link>Tuition and Fees</a></li>
   <li><link>Our Campus</a></li>
 </ul>
</nav>

</body>
```

CSS:

```
#top_bar {
 margin:1em 0;
 margin-left: 70em;
 list-style:none;

 /* Lucinda Grande is the font used on the website from Apple. */
 font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", Verdana, Arial, Helvetica,  sans-serif; 
 letter-spacing:-0.5px;
 font-size:13px;

 /* Apply a subtle text-shadow to the text */
 text-shadow: 0 -1px 3px #202020;


 width:426px; 
 height:.5px;    
 -moz-border-radius:4px;
 -webkit-border-radius:4px;
 border-radius:4px;    
 -moz-box-shadow: 0px 3px 3px #cecece;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 3px 3px #cecece;
 box-shadow: 0 3px 4px #8b8b8b;
 }
```

Please help!

Comment: Add a specific width to your `body` so your page gets a scrollbar when your resize the window.

Answer (score 0):

Add media queries to your CSS like:

```
@media screen and (max-width:1000px){
     #your_id{
        margin: 0 0 0 10%;
     }
}
```

See [this](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/)